# focusout on any TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-focusout

I want to call a javascript function `on focusout` of a textbox. I have quite a lot of `TextBoxes` so to prevent a listener for every `TextBox` is there any possibility of calling the same javascript method on any `textBox` `focusout` passing the value of the Textbox as an parameter?

I want to do this on client side and not on server side.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, it's as simple as

```
$("input").focusout(function(){
    //Whatever you want
});
```

As pointed out by Milney, you probably want to interact with that specific textbox.  To do this, you'd use "$(this)" as a selector.

```
$("input").focusout(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "beige");
});
```

Comment: Note: If you need access to the specific textbox that triggered the event, you can use $(this) inside the event handler

Comment: That's probably what he wanted to know in the first place.  I went ahead and put that in the answer, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

The blur event occurs when the  field loses focus.

Try this:

```
$("input").blur(function(){
 //alert("ok")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
$("input").focusout(function(){
  var tBval = $(this).val();
  console.log(tBval);
  
  // OR Call a function passing the value of text box as parameter
  //myFunction(tBval);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```